# payable modifier with transfer() in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to play with a deposit and withdraw an ETH token in the smart contract.

```
contract A

function deposit() public payable{
  require(msg.value >= 0, "Value amount to be deposit");
  withdraw(msg.value);
}

function withdraw(uint256 _amount) internal{
   uint256 amount = 2 * _amount //modifying the amount(bonus or whatsoever)
   payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
}
```

The above snippet is the simple form deposit and withdraw function.
Here the deposit works fine, deposit the certain ETH from the account to the contract address.
At the end of the execution it calls withdraw but still, the transfer function takes the **msg.value** as a parameter it seems to override the amount parameter. I've validated those transactions in remix ide.

Does anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the contract with a receive() function to receive ETH. In the hardhat script the owner transfers 100ETH to the contract to simulate your issue. Edited the contract and everything seems to work just fine.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract ContractA {
    event Received(address sender, uint value);

    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function deposit() public payable{
        require(msg.value >= 0, "Value amount to be deposit");
        withdraw(msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) internal{
        console.log(_amount);
        uint256 amount = 2 * _amount; //modifying the amount(bonus or whatsoever)
        console.log(amount);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

Hardhat script that transfers 100 ETH and deposits 5ETH to the contract:

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

const hre = require("hardhat");
async function main() {
  const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  const deposit = await ethers.getContractFactory("ContractA");
  const depositInstance = await deposit.deploy();
  await depositInstance.deployed();

  const depositContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ContractA");
  const instance = await depositContract.attach(`${depositInstance.address}`);

  const contractBalance = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(
    `${depositInstance.address}`
  );
  console.log("contract balance before tx", contractBalance.toString());

  await owner.sendTransaction({
    to: depositInstance.address,
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", 18),
  });
  const contractBalanceAfter = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(
    `${depositInstance.address}`
  );
  // Should be 100 ETH
  console.log("contract balance after tx", contractBalanceAfter.toString());

  // About 9899.99 ETH
  const ownerBalance = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(`${owner.address}`);
  console.log(
    `Owner balance before deposit ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(
      ownerBalance.toString(),
      18
    )}`
  );
  // After deposit balance should be 105 ETH
  await instance
    .connect(owner)
    .deposit({ value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", 18) });

  // After withdraw the balance should be 95ETH
  const contractBalanceAfterContract = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(
    `${depositInstance.address}`
  );
  console.log(
    "contract after contract interaction",
    contractBalanceAfterContract.toString()
  );

  // 9899.99 - 5 + 10 = 9904.99
  const ownerBalanceAfter = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(
    `${owner.address}`
  );
  console.log(
    `Owner balance before deposit ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(
      ownerBalanceAfter.toString(),
      18
    )}`
  );
}
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Running the script shows it works as expected

```
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
contract balance before tx 0
contract balance after tx 100000000000000000000
Owner balance before deposit 9899.999469435601476844
5000000000000000000
10000000000000000000
contract after contract interaction 95000000000000000000
Owner balance before deposit 9904.999416266040763879
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help. Really awesome work!

Yeah! I got the last point, it transfers everything to the user. I need to send certain from contract to user address.

Have you checked with enough amount in the contract?

Like a contract holds 50 ETH and you made a deposit which calls both (deposit - 5 ETH and withdraw of 10 ETH). Even the contract has more balance, but still withdraw makes transfer only 5 ETH. that's the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the issue. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @developerjordy Great help. Now I'm clearly understood my mistake. Again Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation of the test case using hardhat.